# Sheafification of cohomology presheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

Given a complex of sheaves $F$ of abelian groups over a topological space $X$, I am trying to figure out whether the cohomology sheaf $H^n(F)$ is isomorphic to the sheafification of the presheaf $U\to H^n(\Gamma(U;F))$. I know that the two agree on stalks since the stalk functor is exact but is the one the sheafification of the other?

Comment: What is your definition of $H^n(F)$ as a sheaf on $X$?

Comment: It is the cohomology in the category of sheaves, so it is the sheafification of the cokernel of the morphism from the sheafification of the Image to the kernel of the respective boundary maps. In other words my question translates to whether sheafifying once is the same as sheafifying twice (sheafification of both image and cokernel) in this case.

Comment: Sheafification is exact and idempotent, so yes, there is no problem.